# Date Formatting: Output Database Date in Same Format As System.today()

Tags: datetime, date

I have a date field in my object. After I fire a select query , the returned format of the date is :

```
2014-09-16T11:55:00.000Z
```

I have a requirement where I need to convert the above date into `System.today()` format.
Any inputs in this regard is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The field that you query is a date time field by the looks of it. In order to get the date component of that you need to use the [DateTime.date()](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_date) method.

Comment: Thanks Bachovski,But when I use DateTime.date() it gives the following error: "Variable does not exist: DateTime".

Comment: @PravalikaMaram use with DateTime instance not with "DateTime" itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following method to get DateTime in System.today()  formate

```
public Date getdateOnly(DateTime fieldValue){
  return fieldValue.date();
}
```

Please mark this as an answer if this helps you :).

Answer (score -1):

You will need to format the string/object into valid string first then convert to date:

```
    System.debug(formatDate('2014-09-16T11:55:00.000Z'));
    public static Date formatDate(Object dateObject)
    {
        String dateString = String.valueOf(dateObject);
        List<String> dateStringList = dateString.split('T');
        if(dateStringList.size()==2)
        {
            return Date.valueOf(dateStringList[0]);
        }
        return null;
    }
```